# Spring Security 3.1.4: Cannot access target page due to anonymousUser authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When a user password is reset, user is supposed to goto security questions page instead user is kicked back to login page. After enabling spring debug logs i noticed spring is creating anonymousUser authentication.

Am using Spring security 3.1.4

Below are my app logs

```
2014-09-08 13:34:42,355 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache |  | bzyJYL3H4y4h | DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[https://qa-cp/PP/enduser/securityQuestions.do?clear=true]
2014-09-08 13:34:42,355 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter |  | bzyJYL3H4y4h | Calling Authentication entry point.
2014-09-08 13:34:42,355 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy |  | bzyJYL3H4y4h | Redirecting to 'https://qa-cp/PP/index.do'
2014-09-08 13:34:42,355 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | bzyJYL3H4y4h | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2014-09-08 13:34:42,356 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | bzyJYL3H4y4h | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-09-08 13:34:43,369 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,370 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-09-08 13:34:43,371 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6814b7b1. A new one will be created.
2014-09-08 13:34:43,371 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WelcomePageRedirectFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,373 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'InternalAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,374 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,375 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,375 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,376 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,377 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2014-09-08 13:34:43,378 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | queryString: arg1=clear=true; arg2=null (property not equals)
2014-09-08 13:34:43,379 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | saved request doesn't match
2014-09-08 13:34:43,379 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,380 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,381 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter | anonymousUser | orAnz9si9ErQ | Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 10.9.120.74; SessionId: C69492D05E3009DEC64122CC220B9A4B; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,382 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,383 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:43,384 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy | anonymousUser | orAnz9si9ErQ | /index.do at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
```

After keep trying loggin for couple of minutes then spring authenticates the user. below are the logs

```
2014-09-08 13:34:51,089 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,090 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-09-08 13:34:51,092 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6814b7b1. A new one will be created.
2014-09-08 13:34:51,093 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WelcomePageRedirectFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,100 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'InternalAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,100 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,101 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | /j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,102 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | Request is to process authentication
2014-09-08 13:34:51,103 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | Authentication attempt using com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.security.service.CPDaoAuthenticationProvider
2014-09-08 13:34:51,110 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,110 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-09-08 13:34:51,111 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6814b7b1. A new one will be created.
2014-09-08 13:34:51,111 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WelcomePageRedirectFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,112 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'InternalAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,112 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /j_spring_security_check at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,113 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /j_spring_security_check at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,114 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | Request is to process authentication
2014-09-08 13:34:51,114 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | Authentication attempt using com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.security.service.CPDaoAuthenticationProvider
2014-09-08 13:34:51,164 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@79680fbd: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@49520377: Username: test1@dc.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 11.22.22.33; SessionId: C69492D05E3009DEC64122CC220B9A4B; Not granted any authorities
2014-09-08 13:34:51,178 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@79680fbd: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@49520377: Username: test1@dc.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 11.22.22.33; SessionId: C69492D05E3009DEC64122CC220B9A4B; Not granted any authorities
2014-09-08 13:34:51,355 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy | test1@dc.com | orAnz9si9ErQ | Redirecting to '/PP/enduser/securityQuestions.do?clear=true'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,356 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository | test1@dc.com | orAnz9si9ErQ | SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@79680fbd: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@79680fbd: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@49520377: Username: test1@dc.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 11.22.22.33; SessionId: C69492D05E3009DEC64122CC220B9A4B; Not granted any authorities'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,357 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-09-08 13:34:51,396 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy | test1@dc.com | IfMNPOKYArlz | Redirecting to '/PP/enduser/securityQuestions.do?clear=true'
2014-09-08 13:34:51,397 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository | test1@dc.com | IfMNPOKYArlz | HttpSession is now null, but was not null at start of request; session was invalidated, so do not create a new session
2014-09-08 13:34:51,398 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter |  | IfMNPOKYArlz | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-09-08 13:34:52,372 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | /enduser/securityQuestions.do?clear=true at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-08 13:34:52,373 DEBUG | org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository |  | orAnz9si9ErQ | Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@79680fbd: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@79680fbd: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@49520377: Username: test1@dc.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 11.22.22.33; SessionId: C69492D05E3009DEC64122CC220B9A4B; Not granted any authorities'
```

Update: security-applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:bean id="trustedAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
   <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="X-Remote-Authenticate"/>
   <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
   <beans:property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false" />
</beans:bean>   


<!-- LOCAL LOGIN CONFIGURATION -->
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        request-matcher-ref="localAuthRequestMatcher">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN_PERMISSION')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/system/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN_PERMISSION')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/enduser/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/changePassword.do" access="permitAll"/>      
  <intercept-url pattern="/index.do" access="isAnonymous()" />
  <custom-filter after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="welcomePageRedirectFilter" />
  <custom-filter before="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="internalAuthenticationFilter" />
  <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>
  <form-login login-page="/index.do" authentication-failure-handler-ref="DCAuthenticationFailureHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
  <http-basic />
  <anonymous />      
  <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="customSessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />  
  <logout success-handler-ref="localLogoutSuccessHandler" />       
</http> 

<beans:bean id="exceptionTranslator"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg><beans:ref bean="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" /></beans:constructor-arg>    
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="localLogoutSuccessHandler"
  class="com.dc.core.security.authentication.impl.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler">
  <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.do" />          
</beans:bean>
```

Code which redirects the user to securityquestions page

```
@Component
@Primary
public class CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
@Autowired
private CollaborationSecurityService      collabSecurityService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationFilterConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

@Autowired
private FailedLoginsLock                  failedLoginsLock;

private static final String               SECURITY_QUESTIONS_URL = "/enduser/securityQuestions.do?clear=true";

private static final Logger               LOGGER                 = Logger.getInstance("dc.auth");

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response,
            this.onCPAuthenticationSuccessUrl(request, response, authentication));
}

public String onCPAuthenticationSuccessUrl(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Successful Authentication Principal--> " + authentication.getPrincipal());
    boolean isNewSession = false;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        if (!sessionHandler.sessionAlreadyBound(sessionFactory)) {
            session = sessionHandler.initiateSession(sessionFactory);
            sessionHandler.beginTransaction(session);
            isNewSession = true;
        }

        if (!SecurityHelper.isCurrentUserAnonymous()
                && collabSecurityService.needSecurityQuestionSetup(authentication.getName()))
            return SECURITY_QUESTIONS_URL;
        else

        return super.onAuthenticationSuccessUrl(request, response, authentication);

    } finally {
        if (isNewSession) {
            sessionHandler.endTransaction(false, sessionFactory);
        }
    }
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
}
```

}

I dont really know whats going wrong with spring authentication. I really appreciate someone's help on this

Comment: can you share spring config and code? it's impossible to take a look at your code and guess the nature of the problem

Comment: @SezinKarli Am trying to update my question with code and config but it seems my questions already has 30000 characters and its not letting me add any additional characters

Comment: @RanPaul you can remove some of the log. The config will tell us more...

Comment: @Evgeni updated question with securityContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

I face with same issue in spring security 5, maybe help to another with similar problems.

fixing priority of filters calling can be help to resolve this problem.

if your authentication filter authenticate your user before calling `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` class, this class reset context and your user clear from context:

```
    HttpRequestResponseHolder holder = new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request, response);
    SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = this.repo.loadContext(holder);
    try {
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);
    ...
    }
```

and in next chain of filters your authenticated user missing and `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` register `anonymousUser` when authentication is null.

ultimately you have to change priority of your filter after this `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`.

for example in non xml config you can set  your filter priority like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      ...

      http.addFilterAfter(YOUR_FILTER_CLASS, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);

      ...
   }
}
```